# What is the form of local basis functions for 27-nodes cubic element in FEM?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-method

consider the nodes is [image],now I want to solve a pde and I'm trying to find local basis of this nodes,my goal is to find a multivariable polynomial with 27 unknown parameters so how can we find it, for the case of 20 nodes I'have found it

Comment: The polynomials of degree up to 2 in each coordinate direction have $3^3$ parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the value of $f(x,y,z)$ at these nodes you can approximate the derivative $\partial^j_x \partial_y^k \partial_z^\ell f$ so long as $j,k,\ell\leq 2$. Your polynomial space is thus the polynomials which are of degree $2$ or less *in each variable*.

The most natural basis for this space is the product of usual Lagrange polynomials in each dimension. For example, if our nodes are $\{0,1,2\}^3$ then the basis element which is $1$ at the origin and $0$ at the other nodes is
$$ \phi_{(0,0,0)}(x,y,z) = \frac{(x-1)(x-2)(y-1)(y-2)(z-1)(z-2)}{(0-1)^3(0-2)^3} $$

Edit: this basis is not unique, but it is natural in the sense that it is dual to the "evaluation at nodes" functionals. [Brenner and Scott](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-4338-8) is a standard reference on finite elements. I have also used [Ern and Guermond](https://link.springer.com/978-1-4757-4355-5)

Comment: Could you please tell me is the basis unique?

Comment: could you please recommend some reference text?

Comment: added some more info @吴yuer